Terraform: Error: 400-InvalidParameter, Invalid page
Terraform plan fails with Error: 400-InvalidParameter, Invalid page..
Running on OCI, error detail:
│   with module.smth.data.oci_marketplace_listing_packages.test_listing_packages,
│   on .terraform/modules/smth/data.tf line 102, in data "oci_marketplace_listing_packages" "test_listing_packages":
│  102: data "oci_marketplace_listing_packages" "test_listing_packages" {

The calling source:
data "oci_marketplace_listing_packages" "test_listing_packages" {
  listing_id      = data.oci_marketplace_listing.test_listing.id
  package_version = var.package_version
}

How could this be debugged/resolved?
Update: this might be related to a specific package version not being available.
